# How to make a descriptions list inline?

Tags: html, css

I am setting up a descriptions list and I would like the terms and descriptions to be on one line each like so:

**Term**  **Term**  **Term**  **Term**  **Term**  **Term**
**Desc**  **Desc**  **Desc**  **Desc**  **Desc**  **Desc**

The caveat to this is that I will be making the background of the term a black circle and I need to center the term vertically and horizontally within the background circle and the description centered below the term.

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6QbP/) and here is what I have so far for HTML/CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
dl dt {
    background:#000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px; 
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
}
dd {
    text-align:center;
    width:50px;
}
</style>

<dl>
      <dt>N</dt>
      <dd>6.0%</dd>
      <dt>P</dt>
      <dd>12.0%</dd>
      <dt>K</dt>
      <dd>2.0%</dd>
      <dt>Zn</dt>
      <dd>1.0%</dd>
      <dt>Fe</dt>
      <dd>0.3%</dd>
      <dt>Mn</dt>
      <dd>0.04%</dd>
      <dt>Cu</dt>
      <dd>0.05%</dd>
</dl>
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a way because the elements are staggered. It would be easy if you had wrapper around each `dt/dd` group or if they were split into a row of `dt` or a row of `dd`

Comment: Yea your html format need to change for this to happen

Comment: Ok, so basically I just need to wrap each term/description pair in a div and then float those divs left? Or is it more complicated than that? Thanks!

Comment: That's about it, yup.

Comment: your datas deserve to be hold in a table, do not feel ashame to do so :)

Comment: Ok wrapping each dt/dd pair in a div and floating the div left worked great. Is this the correct way to approach this, or should I set it up as a table like GCyrillus suggested? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done without HTML structure change

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/8fc59/)

```
dl {
    position:relative;
    left:-90px;
}
dl dt {
    background:#000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    left:90px;
}
dd {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:60px;
}
```